# Sincronizar movimentos do player e do host

Tags: c#, unity3d

Olá. Estou fazendo um projeto de escola e estou seguindo o tutorial do Unity Multiplayer Netorking. Tudo funcionou corretamente, porém o tutorial ensina a ter um player e um host, ambos cada um com um "personagem" que se movimenta independentemente do outro. O que eu preciso fazer é o "personagem" de cada um deles terem movimentos sincronizados. Por exemplo se eu mover um deles pro lado, preciso que o personagem do outro jogador também se mova para o lado. Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

O tutorial que segui pra fazer é esse: https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/s/multiplayer-networking

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Não sei até que ponto do tutorial você seguiu, mas nesse tutorial, o que faz com que o os personagens tenham movimentos independentes (cada um controla o seu) é a verificação no código de movimentação do personagem.

```html
if (!isLocalPlayer)
{
    return;
}
```

Ele checa se você é o localPlayer ou seja, o controlador daquele personagem, e então "cancela" a execução do script, caso você não seja.

Assim você acaba controlando só o seu personagem. Se você tirar esse if do código de movimentação. Quando o host ou o player se mexerem o outro se mexerá também.

Espero ter ajudado. Abçs